# Is it possible to have Skype for Android automatically answer calls?

Tags: skype, auto-answer

I have this working well for the Skype client on Ubuntu Linux, but I don't see any option to do this in the Android client.

I would like to configure the Skype client for Android to automatically answer calls from contacts.  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I have developed an app which dials automatically via skype depending on the phone no. So I think it will be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently and sadly, there's no such option to allow the action of auto-answer an incoming Skype call.

You can keep an eye out on this threads, maybe in a nearby feature such solution will arrive:

- [Skype Support Network: Auto answer incoming call on Android OS](http://community.skype.com/t5/Android/Auto-answer-incoming-call-on-Android-OS/td-p/262324)
- [XDA Developers forum thread: [RQ] Skype auto answer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1156813)
- [XDA Developers forum thread: [Q] Skype Auto Answer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1672758)

Additionally, 3rd party solutions aren't possible to this end, since Skype uses a proprietary protocol with no available API as explained on this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6495891/352449).

Comment: Unfortunately Skype for Android DOES automatically answer calls. If my phone is logged into skype and someone calls, it always automatically picks up after the second ring if I don't do anything. I asked about this in the skype support forum and they said the next version of skype will have a new feature that will allow android users to disable auto-answer.